# Weired 'syntax error: unexpected end of file' in bash script

Tags: bash

I can't figure out what is wrong with following script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ "$1" = "x" ] 
then
  echo Pushing web on sharada to origin.
else if [ "$1" = "y" ] 
then 
  echo Pulling web on sharada from origin.
else 
  echo "Usage : arg x to push or y to pull."
fi
```

I am on linux (Ubuntu) in `xterm`.

Comment: You'd better use the `elif` keyword in bash (`help if` for more info).

Comment: I am surprised that `bash` could not produce a better error.

Comment: my bash told me to look for the error in line#11, which is exactly where the `fi` was missing

Comment: @umlaeute I would have expected `missing fi` in addition of line no in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing closing "fi" at the end.
the `else if` construct really is not an `elif` continuation, but instead the new `if` lives within the `else` clause of the previous `if`.

so, properly formatted you should have:

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ "$1" = "x" ] 
then
  echo Pushing web on sharada to origin.
else 
  if [ "$1" = "y" ] 
  then 
    echo Pulling web on sharada from origin.
  else 
    echo "Usage : arg x to push or y to pull."
  fi
fi # <-- this closes the first "if"
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `elif`, not `else if`, as shown below:

```
if [ "$1" = "x" ] 
then
  echo Pushing web on sharada to origin.
elif [ "$1" = "y" ] 
then 
  echo Pulling web on sharada from origin.
else 
  echo "Usage : arg x to push or y to pull."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `if`s, therefore you need two `fi`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem described in the questioned has already been solved. I just wanted to share my experience here because the error message I got was the same, even if the reason and the solution was slightly different.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "a"

if [ -f x.txt ]; then \
    echo "b" \
fi;

echo "c"
```

This script produced the same error message and the solution was to add the missing semicolon to the end of the `echo "b"` line:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "a"

if [ -f x.txt ]; then \
    echo "b" ; \
fi;

echo "c"
```

The direct reason was the same as it was in the original question. The `if` didn't have its closing pair `fi`. The reason, however, was that the `fi` line blended into the previous line, due to the missing `;` semicolon.